# Getting jLabel image url in Java

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, imageicon, getresource

I'll make it short.

I've put a jLbl_show and in a if condition I've set an image for it.

```
if(int c==1){
  jLbl_show0.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/img/wrong.png")));
}
else{
  jLbl_show0.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/img/ok.png")));
}
```

But, as now the image is set i need to **take the image URL to another condition**. which is like;

```
if(imageURL is "/img/ok.png"){ do somthing }
elseif (imgURL is "/img/wrong.png"){ do something }
```

is there a way to do this?

Comment: Your question is a bit vague, could you be more specific

Comment: Store a `boolean` with the same scope as `jLbl_show0` when setting the image.

Comment: Do you mean you want to do a string comparison? The image url compared to "ok.png"

Comment: `int c=1` what kind of boolean is this, anyway...

Comment: 1) Add @M.M. if you want to notify them of a comment.  2) Check code compiles before posting it. 3) Have you solved the problem? 4) In your edit you managed to override my earlier edit.  Take more care in future!  Make sure to use the "share | **edit** | close | flag" control on the lower left.

Comment: @AndrewThompson now I got the OP's comment...

Comment: *"now I need to get the image url back."*  So change the `boolean` to an `URL`, and store the `URL` before passing it to the `ImageIcon`.  But using a `boolean` seems cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do something like this:

```
boolean flag = false;

if(someBoolean){
  jLbl_show0.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/img/wrong.png")));
  flag = true;
}
else{
  jLbl_show0.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/img/ok.png")));
}

if(flag){something}
else{something}
```