# The picture in Jlabel (with ImageIO)

Tags: java, swing, url, jlabel, javax.imageio

Could you tell me how can I download image from Url (ex: from  "http://www.google.ru/intl/en_com/images/logo_plain.png") to `JLabel` but without saving it on HDD?

Could you give me an easy example?
All I need is to put the image from the `URL` to `JLabel` (with ImageIO for ex.)

Comment: this can be useful :) 

> [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13188874/getting-jlabel-image-url-in-java][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13188874/getting-jlabel-image-url-in-java

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13188874/getting-jlabel-image-url-in-java][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13188874/getting-jlabel-image-url-in-java

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(new URL("http://www.google.ru/intl/en_com/images/logo_plain.png")));
```

This going to throw a number of exceptions, so beware

Comment: FWIW: No need to go through `ImageIO` (although it is not incorrect), you can use the `URL` directly in the `ImageIcon` constructor

Comment: @VladPavlov ImageIcon has the benefit of using a background thread for reading the aimed, this means that it won't block the EDT while its downloading/loading the image.  ImageIO will return only after the image has finished downloading. Which is best will depend on your needs

Comment: @GuillaumePolet  One aspect of `ImageIcon` that I dislike is that it will fail silently if handed an `URL` that does not point to an image it supports.  (Though I have to admit 'image loading' becomes a complex & arcane subject in some corner cases e.g. don't use `ImageIO` for an animated GIF such as http://1point1c.org/gif/thum/plnttm.gif - you end up with first frame only..)

Answer (score 2):

Since you don't seem to require using ImageIO even though you mention it few times, this is the simplest way I know:

```
label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(new URL(urlString)));
```

Comment: One thing to be careful of is `ImageIcon` fails silently if the image can't be loaded.